# How can I set a key attribute?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have this class in python google app engine:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    belongsTo = db.Key()
```

My question is, how do I create a key object, for example I want to say that it belongsTo person with id 1, I tried this but it doesn't work

```
b = foo.Book(name="foo book", belongsTo="1")
b.put()
```

I also tried doing

```
belongsTo = key(1)
```

How can I insert a foreign key?

Comment: `db.Key` is not a property class - so this will not work. The only valid things you can put on a model are property classes-  eg, `db.ReferenceProperty` as Moishe suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an arbitrary Key() (unless that's really what you want), define your Book model so that it explicitly references a Person, like this (and with a pretend Person class for clarity)

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Book(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    belongsTo = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
```

then you can do stuff like:

```
book = Book.get(book_key)
owner_name = book.belongsTo.name
```

and

```
person = Person.get(person_key)
books_owned_by_person = person.book_set.get()
```

See the [Types and Property Classes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) App Engine documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the model from Moishe's answer:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Book(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    belongsTo = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
```

This is how you assign foreign key `Person` to a `Book`:

```
person_key = db.Key.from_path('Person', '1')   # '1' is key name of person

book = Book(name = 'foo book', belongsTo = person_key)
```